# UIGestureRecognizer blocking table view scrolling

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using a custom `UIGestureRecognizer` subclass to track gestures on my `InfoView` class. The `InfoView` class is a subview of a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass called `InfoCell`.

I've added my gesture recognizer to my root view (the parent view of everything else on screen, because the purpose of my custom gesture recognizer is to allow dragging of `InfoCell`  views between tables). Now, everything works as it should except one thing. I'm using the following code in my `UIGestureRecognizer` subclass to detect touches on the `InfoView` view:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView *touchView = [[touches anyObject] view];
    if ([touchView isKindOfClass:[InfoView class]]) {
        // Do stuff
    }
```

The problem here is that the touches on the `InfoView` object are being intercepted, therefore they are not being forwarded to the `UITableView` which contains the `InfoCell`, which is the parent view of the `InfoView`. This means that I can no longer scroll the table view by dragging on the `InfoView` view, which is an issue because the `InfoView` covers the entire `InfoCell`.

Is there any way I can forward the touches onto the table view so that it can scroll? I've tried a bunch of things already:

`[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];`

`[touchView.superview.superview touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];` (`touchView.superview.superview` gets a reference to its parent `UITableView`)

But nothing has worked so far. Also, the `cancelsTouchesInView` propery of my `UIGestureRecognizer` is set to `NO`, so thats not interfering with the touches.

Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a line in my `touchesBegan` method that set the `state` property of the gesture recognizer to `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`. Removing this line seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 26):

Check out the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method: `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`

If this returns YES it will prevent your gesture recognizer from stomping on the one that UIScrollView is using to detect scrolling.

Comment: I have been beating my head on the wall on this one. Thanks ! :D

Answer (score 9):

UIGestureRecognizer has a property "cancelsTouchesInView" which is set to YES by default. This means that touches in a UIView are cancelled when a gesture is recognized. Try to set it to NO to allow the UIScrollView to receive further touch events.

Answer (score 3):

You can try add this  notification

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if ([gestureRecognizer class] == [UIPanGestureRecognizer class]) {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRec = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
        CGPoint point = [panGestureRec velocityInView:self];
        if (fabsf(point.x) > fabsf(point.y) ) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: this is the right answer, prevent the panGesture to start if gesture is vertical.